# Challenges in loading images from CDN on multiple host name for e-Commerce site built on Nopcommerce

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-3, optimization, nopcommerce

I am working on a ecommerce site built on the top of Nop Commerce 2.3. We want to use CDN for loading all static contents including its images, but not sure how to do this with NopCommerce.

Nopcommerce is set to save binary of images in db at the time of inserting product, and then it generates thumb or re-sized / optimized images at the run time as and when required and stored them in the content folder of the same application for retrieving on page during load time.

Now, suppose on some page, lets say, Home Page, we have 70 product images. I want to distribute it across four host name, so each host name will serve 17/18 images.

This is definitely to save some time in image loading.

Now the Question is:

How to do it in best way in NopCommerce?

The challenges are:

1. Changing in nop commerce code to load images from CDN instead of its application\content folder. This is not an issue and is fine to manage.
2. To implement this correctly we might need some mechanism that checks for image on CDN if it doesn't exist, then we might need to transfer the image from content folder to appropriate folder at CDN maybe ? (suggest), and if it doesn't exist in content folder, then need to generate suitable image first and then transfer it.

I'm concerned about this 2nd challenge, and wants to understand the best approach to do this. Moreover, how to do this... specifically check if image exists in CDN or not?

Not very much sure, how to do this? And is it okay or do you suggest something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the OVH CDN, you simply point your dns to the CDN dns, add the static file's extensions to the CDN configuration, and let it work for you. All other extensions will pass through. No code to change.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get it exactly.

Comment: Set www.yoursite.com to have the ip of the CDN. In the config of the CDN, add the file extensions you want to cache and set the IP of you server.

Comment: Didn't get what you want to explain... Pls explain.

Comment: customer www.yoursite.com => [CDN server] => [CDN cache *.jpg] => customer

Comment: customer www.yoursite.com => [CDN server] => [not jpg/not cacheable] => [your server] => customer

Comment: Every requests to static files are served by the CDN. Every requests to dynamic pages pass through the CDN.

Comment: Oh... so first each request goes to CDN, then if its in CDN, it will serve from there, else from our server... Is this what you mean to say..

Comment: well yes, BUT it will only cache requests matching the regex you setup. Every other requests will go through.

Comment: Hi, Can you point me to some case study or some tutorial / best practices as how to do this?